# PHP-CSS approach to get rid of external, internal CSS

Tags: php, css

I want to create a PHP-CSS approach for my web applications. So I don't need to make any external CSS file, nor internal CSS, neither the inline styles. This approach will work as:

```
... html code ...

<?php
_c( '
header .nav {
  background: yellow;    
}
header .nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
');
?>

... more html code and other php-css chunks ...
```

The function _c() will keep collecting all php-css chunks from entire application on the go, and finally, write all these chunks in a CSS file, compress or minimize and include using `<link ..` tag at the end.

This way, I won't need to even see the face of .css file. All my php-css chunks will be available on their related pages. So I won't need to keep a bunch of css files open and edit them.

If I use this approach for a huge application, what could be side effects on usability, performance, memory consumption, speed of app etc?

Comment: Ultimately, you are creating a CSS file, but the resulting file will be hard to maintain since it is generated dynamically.  If your application gets large enough, you will get CSS rules that conflict and it will be challenging to fix the issues.

Comment: just use any of existing bundling approaches, why to develop own bad design?